# Getting difference between two dates like in facebook, instagram comment section

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, relativedatetimeformatter

I am working on an app in which i have to display the date/time difference between current date and posted date in format like "1 hour ago", "4 days ago"
I got api response in this format

> "created_at": "2022-12-03 05:24:00"

and i am using this code to convert this date string to relative date

```
let dateStr = cell.dateLbl.text //
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        print("==", dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr!) ?? Date())
        
        let exampleDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr!) ?? Date()
        print(exampleDate)
        
        let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
        formatter.unitsStyle = .full
        let relativeDate = formatter.localizedString(for: exampleDate, relativeTo: Date())
        print(relativeDate) 
        cell.dateLbl.text = relativeDate
```

it always return

> "in 0 seconds"

Comment: I got it. What happens is ```dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr!)``` returns ```nil```. So the value of the ```exampleDate``` equals to ```Date()```. So in your calculation you are comparing ```Date()``` and ```Date()```. which is exactly ```0 seconds```. So print your ```dateStr```(before passing it to dateformatter) and check if it is in correct formate. It might have some extra space or any other thing included

Comment: @udi thanks for help i checked and remove the additional spaces ocurred in label. now it is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed the code in the playground and it works fine. So there is nothing much wrong with the logic.

But this is what might happen. If the `dateStr` in an unexpected format `dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr!)` will return `nil`. So the value of the `exampleDate` will be equal to `Date()`.

So in your calculation you are comparing `Date()` and `Date()`. Which are same. So there is no difference and it will return `"in 0 seconds"`.

So print your `dateStr` (before passing it to the `dateformatter`) and check if it is in correct formate. It might have some extra space or any other thing included.